# pygame. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'y'

Tags: python, vector, pygame, logic

i'm learning new for me library pygame with youtube guides.
When i working with vectors x and y i'll have the new error for me

"if main_game.player.direction.x !=1: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'"

```
 if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            if main_game.player.direction.y !=1:
                main_game.player.direction = Vector2(0,-1)
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            if main_game.player.direction.x !=-1:
                main_game.player.direction = Vector2(1,0)
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            if main_game.player.direction.y !=-1:
                main_game.player.direction = Vector2(0,1)
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            if main_game.player.direction.x !=1:
                main_game.player.direction = Vector2(-1,0)
```

MAIN class in my code calling class player where is pygame Vectors
that's looks like:

```
     class MAIN:
        def __init__(self):
        self.player = PLAYER()
        self.point = POINT()
```

and class PLAYER look like that:

```
     class PLAYER:
         def __init__(self):
            self.score = int(0)
            print('your score is:', self.score)
            self.body = [Vector2(5,10), Vector2(4,10), Vector2(3,10)]
            self.direction = [1,0]
            self.new_block = False
```

Why i can't using the Vector.x or y?

Comment: `direction` isn't a `Vector2`, it's a `list`.  I don't see where `direction` is even initialized in your `PLAYER` class.

Answer (score 0):

`self.direction` must be a vector. So initialize it with a vector in the constructor:

```py
class PLAYER:
     def __init__(self):
        self.score = int(0)
        print('your score is:', self.score)
        self.body = [Vector2(5,10), Vector2(4,10), Vector2(3,10)]
            
        self.direction = Vector2(1, 0)   # <---
           
        self.new_block = False
```